# I can't sign into my Facebook account

Tags: facebook

I'm having problems signing into my account. I know my user name but not my password and I can't recover it because I don't have the phone number that's on the account. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to resolve the most common login issues:

1. Resetting your password

To request a new password, click the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate

You can also use the "Forgot your password?" link located near the “Login” button on the Facebook home page.

2. Identifying your account

If you request a new password, you will be asked to identify your account. These tips may help with the process:

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19511

3. Additional resources

Unfortunately, we cannot offer personalized email support for login issues, but you can find more information through these resources:

- Security questions:
  http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=18897
- Recovering your account through friends:
  http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1153
- Login and password frequently asked questions:
  http://www.facebook.com/help/login

---

If you don't have your phone you can log in from a known browser or fill out the following form to contact Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/login_approvals

If you're having trouble receiving your confirmation code via SMS, please fill out this form:

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/174964429275926